# Change of numeraire : quotient

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, geometric-brownian, numeraire

Let's consider $X_1(t)$ a geometric brownian motion (with variable volatility) and $X_2(t)$ a Brownian bridge :

$dX_1(t) = \mu X_1(t) dt + \sigma_1(t) X_1(t) dW(t)$

$dX_2(t) = \frac{b - X_2(t)}{T - t} dt + \sigma_2 dZ(t)$

Assuming that $w$ and $z$ are independant standard BM, how can I get $d\left(\frac{X_1}{X_2}\right)$ ?

I know, from Ito's lemma, that $d\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right) = \frac{dX}{Y} - \frac{XdY}{Y^2} - \frac{dXdY}{Y^2} + \frac{XdY^2}{Y^3}$. I also know that some $\sigma_{ij}$ appear in the multidimensionnal extension for Ito, but i don't understand how it works ...

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hint: Let $X_3 = \frac{X_1}{X_2}$. Then we have $X_1 = X_2 X_3$, and $dX_1 = ...$ Then apply what you know about quadratic variation to $\langle X_1, X_3 \rangle_t$

Comment: What is the crochet between $X_1$ and $X_3$ ? I've never seen that ...

Comment: quadratic variation

Comment: It doesn't really help me. Could you give more details ? Thanks in advance

Comment: $dX_1 = d(X_2 X_3) = X_3dX_2 + X_2 dX_3 + d\langle X_2, X_3\rangle$, which is equal to GBM SDE with variable volatility. Then you can use the polarisation identity of quadratic variation